# Automatically change wifi and bluetooth MAC address

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, privacy

I recently learned that it's quite easy to track people with their wifi MAC address and Bluetooth address in stores, etc. I was wondering if there are any drawbacks of changing these addresses regularly (eg daily) to prevent such tracking? I was also looking for apps that would do this but couldn't find any.

Is it impossible or problematic or conscious people just turn them on/off all the time and the rest doesn't care?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing / spoofing Bluetooth and WiFI Mac addresses are a concern to those who value their privacy , especially to prevent your location being tracked . Mac address of your WiFi router is a dead give away of your location and since most apps ask for "full network access" they can be used to track your physical location.

Changing these is a good idea if you want to prevent that. Unfortunately, this requires root (AFAIK). If your device is rooted and has [xposed-framework](/questions/tagged/xposed-framework) installed, Xposed modules [Xprivacy Lua](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacylua6-0-android-privacy-manager-t3730663) for Android 6.0 and above (not Pie) or [Xprivacy](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/xprivacy-ultimate-android-privacy-app-t2320783) for earlier versions (both by same developer) are well recommended. There are other Xposed modules too that claim to do this.

Except for a small minority most don't care IMO